# spring integration custom transformer returning null values

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have written a custom transformer which I want to convert a json message to java.

```
<int:transformer ref="myCustomTransformer" input-channel="myInputChannel" output-channel="outputMsgChannel"/>
```

Transformer code:

```
@Component ("myCustomTransformer")
```

public class MyCustomTransformer {

```
@Transformer
public Message<Staff> converToObj(Message<String> message){

     return MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Staff()).copyHeaders(message.getHeaders()).build();      
  }

}
```

My `Staff` class:

```
public class Staff {

@JsonProperty("name")   
String name;

@JsonProperty("age")    
String age;

@JsonProperty("status") 
String status;

// setters and getters
```

In my `service-activator` class:

```
  public void handleUser(Staff obj) {

    System.out.println(obj instanceof Staff); // returns true

    System.out.println("Handling the response message from the jms");
    System.out.println(obj.getName());
    System.out.println(obj.getStatus());
    System.out.println(obj.getAge());
}
```

The service activator is displaying that the object is of type staff but all instance variables are coming as null. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I was using older version of `jaxson` jar. The spring docs mentions that the `jaxson` jar should be above version `2.0`.